# How would I find out if items in one list are greater than items in another list?

Tags: python

How would I find out if the numbers in one list are greater than each number in another list? Using a for loop?

```
def s_greater(num_1,num_2):
list_1 = []
list_2 = []

for i in range(len(list_1)):
    for l in range(len(list_2)):
    if i > list_2:
        list_2.append(i)
```

I'm stuck here.

Comment: What you have tried yet??

Comment: Where is your progress yet. Please research before asking

Answer (score 1):

You  can use logic with `zip` such as

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

list_diff = [b - a for a, b in zip(list1, list2)]

if min(list_diff)>0:
        print("All respective elements of the second list are greater than the first one")
```

prints out as desired if all values satisy the condition when ordered respectively within each lists.

Comment: How can I use a for loop can you please look at my example because I'm stuck?

Comment: you don't need such a complex comparison for what you're trying to do. Just replace the values of list1 with list2 within my answer in order to make it suit your case. Btw, pay attention for the indentation @kirk101

Comment: should read `All elements of the *second* list are greater than the first one` I assume.

Answer (score -1):

If the smallest item of a list `list2` is greater than the greatest item of another list `list1` then **all** items of list2 are greater:

```
list1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
list2 = [5, 6, 7, 8]

if min(list2) > max(list1):
    print("All items of the 2nd list are greater than those from the 1st one")
```

If the lists are sorted it is sufficient to compare the last element of one list with the first one of the other list:

```
if list2[-1] > list1[0]:
    print("All items of the 2nd list are greater than those from the 1st one")
```